# How to reset password with Symfony 6.0.2?

Tags: symfony, error-handling

I wanted to set up **composer require symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle** :

```
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I have this error. What should I do ?

Comment: It's going to depend in part on what version of Symfony/PHP you are using.  The [symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/5.2/security/reset_password.html#generating-the-reset-password-code) needs to be installed before running the reset-password command.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my description.

Comment: Consider adding Symfony/PHP/Composer version information to your question.  I ran a quick test on a 6.1 app and the bundle installed cleanly.